# Reduce size of Vue component library in Nuxt App

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-cli

our Team created a custom Vue component library with ~50 Vue components using the command:

`vue-cli-service build --modern --target lib --name theLibrary src/main.js`

and this main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import upperFirst from 'lodash/upperFirst'
import camelCase from 'lodash/camelCase'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

const requireComponent = require.context('./components/', true, /[A-Z]\w+\.(vue)$/)

requireComponent.keys().forEach((fileName) => {
  const componentConfig = requireComponent(fileName)

  const componentName = upperFirst(
    camelCase(
      fileName
        .split('/')
        .pop()
        .replace(/\.\w+$/, '')
    )
  )

  Vue.component(componentName, componentConfig.default || componentConfig)
})
```

The resulting theLibrary.common.js has a size of 4,5MB.

Then we import the library into our nuxt application via a plugin (theLibrary.js):

```
import 'theLibrary'
```

and added this into our nuxt.config plugins list:
`'@plugins/theLibrary'`

But with the library becoming bigger and bigger, the inital load time of our site got slower and slower. Presumably because all components of the library are getting initialized even if  only a few are needed on the current page.
But how can we stop this behaviour and only load the required components for each page that the user currently visits.

We tried a lot of little tweaks at various configurations (vue, webpack, nuxt config,...) but without any luck.

Right now we only use a vue.config.js in the library project, with no relevant configuration regarding this problem. (only some css and font configuration)

dev-Dependencies of the library:

```
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.8",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
    ... and much more ...
```

Comment: To use that one efficiently you will need to be able to do `import {myCoolConponent } from 'theLibrary'` to only pick the needed component rather than the whole thing thanks to named imports + tree-shaking. And to load that per page/component and not on a global scope as of right now (in a plugin) because as you saw, it is doing that globally before your Nuxt app starts.

Comment: Exactly, but how do i get my lib to allow such imports? I tried to do it like vuetify, because it is open source and a vue component library like our project. 
Unfortunately, they use .ts files instead of .vue files. I thought it might be enough to switch our library from JS to TS to adopt the build process from vuetify in a customized way. However, I have not been able to get it to run even after many hours. There are always errors when reading the vue files. Is there a good example of this anywhere or a term I can google for?

Comment: Vuetify is maybe a too big project overall, not sure it is great for a start. On top of maybe not being the best approach neither. You don't need to use TS, especially if you don't use it already. "how to create treeshakable js library" should be a good start, go simple and easy, then you will be able to ship more complex components.